# Snippets plugin not working in VS code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I've installed The [JavaScript Snippet pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=akamud.vscode-javascript-snippet-pack) and restarted VS Code. But I still can't see any snippets beeing added when writing JavaScript. My understanding is that `ae` followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> should give me the following code:

```
${1:document}.addEventListener('${2:load}', function(e) {
${3:// body}
});
```

But instead I get

```
RsaOaepParams
```

What can I do to fix the snippet package so it starts working?

Answer (score 0):

After a restart the problem is solved, still have no idea why it wouldnt work, but now Im back on track!